# pip install lxml error with x86_64

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I have Redhat CEL6 running on the x86_64 box. I am trying to install "lxml" and keep on getting the following error. Tried installing all dependent packages and dev packages but still couldn't get a way to resolve this.

I tried re-installing gcc which didn't help either.

Any thoughts here ? Here is the error:

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml
gcc -pthread -m32 -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -m32 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -   Isrc/lxml/includes -I/users/cveerapa/pyats/include -I/auto/pysw/cel63/python/3.4.1/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ?PyInit_etree?:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:213700: note: variable tracking size limit exceeded with -fvar-tracking-assignments, retrying without
gcc -pthread -shared -m32 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.so when searching for -lxslt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.a when searching for -lxslt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.so when searching for -lxslt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.a when searching for -lxslt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxslt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install all the development libraries, but in this case it looks like you are trying to compile the 32bit version of  the library, as you most likely have the 32bit version of Python installed.

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel.i686 libxslt.i686 libxml2-devel.i686 libxslt-devel.i686 python-devel.i686
```

Comment: They are up to date:

Comment: This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.7.6-20.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: ut the "pip install lxml" fails:                                                                                         #########################################################                                                                                                                               pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz (3.7MB)
    100% |????????????????????????????????| 3.7MB 17.3MB/s

Comment: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:213700: note: variable tracking size limit exceeded with -fvar-tracking-assignments, retrying without
    gcc -pthread -shared -m32 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.so when searching for -lxslt
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.a when searching for -lxslt
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.so when searching for -lxslt

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libxslt.a when searching for -lxslt
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxslt
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Have you tried to install / update libsxlt as well? btw which CentOS version are you running? ```cat /etc/redhat-release```

Comment: Here is the distro: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)

Comment: Package libxslt-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Try the following: ```yum install libxslt.i686 libxml2-devel.i686 libxslt-devel.i686 python-devel.i686```

Comment: It might be looking for the 32bit version of the libraries, but I'll try it on 6.7 once I get home.

Comment: This did work.  However later it complained about missing -lz, for that I had to do "sudo yum install zlib-devel.i686". then the "lxml" got installed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem (but 64bit issue) on my RH5.7.  Your problem is 32bit lxml on your Linux.

@eandersson 's advice is useful , I think.

Can you check following command?

1. find /usr/lib* -name libxslt.so
2. yum list installed libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel

I expect 1st result has "/usr/lib/libxslt.so". Because your installer is required 32bit library (-m32).

Also 2nd result should have "*.i686". Not only "*.x86_64" cause of same with above.

If both of them different from my expecting, you may run following:

- yum install libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel

  - actually you need some of them, but I've not guessed before.

I hope, it help some.